# Accessing Nested Dictionaries

Tags: xcode, plist, nsdictionary

Im having a terrible time here! Ive got a plist file as shown in the following link:

http://postimg.org/image/63rhs59qf/

What I need is to have the drug names (Drug1, Drug2, etc) in a tableview, which when clicked the corresponding url and the section they came from are passed to another view controller.

I dont need to know all the code for passing data etc, I just need to know how to access the data and get it into a local array/dictionary from the plist!

I cant get my head around it, and im pretty sure i dont really understand plists, any help would be very gratefully received!!!

Pete

p.s. Im up for re-designing the plist file if that helps - the photo below maybe a better option?? god I dont know!

http://postimg.org/image/wzapyj5ht/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the dictionary from Root use following
Get the path of Plist stored in your application bundle

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDrugList" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Read ROOT from plist, it will return root dictionary with all the sections

```
NSDictionary *sectionDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

TO read specific section Dicionary

```
NSDictionary *section1 = [sectionDictionary objectForKey:@"Section1"]; // returns Section1
NSDictionary *section2 = [sectionDictionary objectForKey:@"Section2"]; // returns Section2
```

To read Drug Value

```
NSString *drug1 = [section1 objectForKey:@"Drug1"]; // returns value for Drug1
```

Comment: its for your first dictionary structure.

Comment: So how would you get all the drugs into one array, and all the urls into another array? im nearly understanding this!!

Comment: i would insist to use your second dictionary structure which you have put at last.